# Pulling data from ALM to Excel

Tags: excel, alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I'm trying to pull data from ALM and save it in an excel sheet. I'm writing the code in the Workflow of ALM. When I write the below single and tried to save, it was throwing error:

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection

Do we have to give any references before writing this code? If so how to give the reference?

Answer (score 0):

it's VBScript, not Visual Basic.

Do not give the type when declaring variables :

write

```
  Dim cn
```

instead of

```
  Dim cn as Whatever
```

Also, if you want to run queries on ALM database from workflow scripts, you can use TDConnection.Command, if your administrator did not restrict its use.